# How to feed dynamically created file to command line unility?

Tags: php, xml, terminal

I have terminal command `some_command -action action_name -file xxx.xml`
This command receive -file parameter which is xml file. I can't create stand alone xml for each request, I would like to form this file dynamically. How can I do this? How can I create it dynamically in php and feed it to terminal utility?

**Update:**

*Utility* - command line utility for billing system, make queries to billing. You need to form request in xml then tell to the utility what command you want to execute and feed special xml file to this command.

Server has FreeBSD installed.

Comment: Can you provide more information about your problem, like what is `some_command` ? Can the command read from a stream? What server environment are you working in? Which scripting environment ?

Comment: Done. I updated my question. "Can the command read from a stream?" I don't know, how to check?

Comment: Does `utility` have any documentation? 
You could generate a random file name, and write to that, execute the command, and then delete the random file afterwards

Comment: I fail to understand what the problem is here. If you say you want to create those xml files one by one by means of php, when why is it a problem to call that CLI utility one by one, each time specifying the correct xml file name?